uwsgi socket not found when started via systemd
I try to start uwsgi (installed manually via pip) in Ubuntu 22.04 as a systemd service, but so far without success. Nginx cannot connect to the uwsgi socket, although the service is running:
2024/05/25 22:46:18 [crit] 25250#25250: *3 connect() to unix:///tmp/website.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server:      website.django, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/website.socket:", host: "website.django"

The service configuration file uwsgi-django.service looks like this –
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for Django
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
Restart=always
User=www-data
Group=www-data
DynamicUser=yes
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

– the socket file uwsgi-django.socket contains this:
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for Django (Socket)
PartOf=uwsgi-django.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/tmp/website.socket

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

– and the webproject.ini file in /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled contains this:
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
socket = /tmp/website.socket
chdir = /var/www/webproject/
module = webproject.wsgi
processes = 10
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

After starting the service, the /tmp directory contains a subdir created by systemd (systemd-private-5f0832defcb246948a1783871729d9b4-uwsgi-django.service-tobdEs) which contains tmp/website.socket – but this is obviously not found by nginx.
If I start uwsgi manually (/var/www/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled), the socket address is read from webproject.ini and is created at /tmp/website.socket (and is found by nginx). What do I need to change about uwsgi-django.socket or uwsgi-django.service to fix this?
Edit: I added Requires=uwsgi-django.socket to the service configuration, and started socket/service in the right order, as suggested by Tom. This takes me one step further, but now I encounter the following error:
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---

But as stated before, the webproject.ini file works fine when uwsgi is called manually.

Does it make a difference if you start the socket manually first? (Or, just add Requires=uwsgi-django.socket to [Unit] of the service.)

Thank you – this takes me one step further (s. the update to my question)!

Why are you using DynamicUser=yes btw? It implies a bunch of stuff.

Btw, I wonder if you actually need / want the socket unit at all. The service / daemon in this case doesn't seem to be something that would be activated via the socket.

Removing DynamicUser gives me yet another error message (error removing unix socket, unlink(): Operation not permitted [core/socket.c line 198]), and without the socket unit, there would be no socket for nginx to talk to (I guess). So the current config – with the addition you suggested – seems to be almost working.

You probably need to set SocketUser= (and maybe SocketGroup=) to www-data. there would be no socket for nginx to talk to The socket unit is not exactly for "getting the socket created". You/nginix couldn't see the socket because you were using DynamicUser=yes, which implies PrivateTmp=yes (and that the daemon creates the socket under /tmp, as per your instruction). While a socket unit does create a socket, it's only useful if you expect when something to talk to the socket, the daemon then gets started ("socket activation").

Ok, so I added SocketUser and SocketGroup to the socket unit, and removed DynamicUser from the service unit. Now the socket is owned by www-data, but the no python application found error persists. I suspected it had to do something with the WorkingDir of the service unit, but setting it to the project home (/var/www/webproject) – as configured with chdir in the webproject.ini – did not help.

I still think you should try to just stop the socket unit (and remove the Requires= line). AFAIK not all programs know how to "inherit" socket created by systemd.

That did it! Thank you!

With Tom Yan's help in the comments (thanks again!), I was able to get a very simple working config:
# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for Django
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
Restart=always
User=www-data
Group=www-data
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/webproject.ini
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/website.socket
chdir = /var/www/webproject/
module = webproject.wsgi
processes = 10
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum = true

I still wonder why the socket activation via systemd described in the uwsgi docs does not work for me (no python application found), because it seems to be the recommended setup ("When using Systemd socket activation, you do not need to specify any socket in your uWSGI configuration; the instance will inherit the socket from Systemd.") – but at least there is a solution.

Have you tried removing the line socket = /tmp/website.socket from /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/webproject.ini though? (If you want to try again, don't forget to add the Requires= line back.)

Yes, I did, but the no python application found error occurs with or without that directive when using the systemd-generated socket.

Found the issue! The error message is created for the first request to the socket if the service unit is not started manually (after the socket unit). After the inital (failed) request, the service unit is available (having been started by the socket unit), and everything works as expected. Many thanks for your patience!

Hmm odd. Normally the socket would "block" until the service / daemon is ready.

Someone else had a similar problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694257/why-systemd-socket-activation-is-not-ready-to-work-on-first-request
